# How do I include multiple proto files in a .NetCore gRPC project?

Tags: .net-core, grpc

I'm creating a .NetCore C# desktop app using gRPC.
I'm attempting to use the Orchestrator pattern (microservices).

The basic design is:

Client (requester)  <-->  Orchestrator <--> multiple different request handlers

Each RequestHandler will have it's own set of messages.

Is it possible to have "Client" GrpcServices within the same project file,
or do I need to include all my proto message definitions within a single file?
With the setup listed below, my projects fail to load.

**Here is the related snippet from my .csproj file:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="../Protos/linuxservice.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
        <Link>Protos/linuxservice.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf> 
    <Protobuf Include="../Protos/orchestrator.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
        <Link>Protos/orchestrator.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="../Protos/service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
        <Link>Protos/service.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    Protobuf Include="../Protos/windowsservice.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
        <Link>Protos/windowsservice.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Usually you expect from people that has a little bit points in the profile to post exactly error on 'fail to load'.... but gosh what do I known ? we try to guess the error as usual..... :(

Answer (score 1):

Well after so much trial and error I managed to create several props and that each one of them is consumed by its respective service.

- Create your proto file
- Check the properties of the file.
- Build Action => Protobuf, compiler grpc subclasses => server only,
  Compile protobuf => yes
- Recompile the project and this automatically generates the Base class
- add your service in app.MapGrpcService

I put the link where he gave me a guide, I hope it helps you.
https://medium.com/@lukastosic/part-1-grpc-its-fairly-simple-c-example-d4b266c4c72e
Blessings